# Can we store and retrieve time in Snowflake with fractional seconds in column of TYPE TIME

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
insert into SRC_DATE_TIME(c4_TIME) values('19:03:51.45256')

select c4_TIME FROM SRC_DATE;
```

Above query is returning this result:

```
19:03:51
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have up to 9 decimal points for fractional seconds. There are a few considerations, including the fact that by default times will display without fractional seconds.

```
-- Define a time field allowing up to nine decimal points for the seconds.
create or replace temporary table MY_TIME(THE_TIME time(9));

-- Insert a time with fractional part
insert into MY_TIME select '12:41:15.123';

 --Will not show fractional seconds by default. 
select * from MY_TIME;

-- Force display of fractional seconds
select to_varchar(THE_TIME, 'HH24:MM:SS.FF') as THE_TIME from MY_TIME;
```

Comment: You could also change your TIME_OUTPUT_FORMAT parameter of the account, user, or session to display the fractional seconds without having to cast to varchar.